# Manual testing JavaScript Number.toLocaleString()

Tags: javascript, localization, formatting

I have localisation set up in my project, with having `Math.round(number).toLocaleString()`. I would like to manually test if this works. Which settings do I need to change to see a change in the formatting? Currently this is displaying in the format of `1,234`, and I'd like to see `1 234` in my application. I'm using a Mac and tried changing the language in Chrome and the system settings for language for Safari (to a language that displays numbers as `1 234`), none of which made any difference. Where does `toLocaleString()` get the location from, and what do I need to change to see the differences when testing manually?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253706/set-different-display-and-format-language-on-macos-sierra

Comment: I was asking a simple question I think. I know how to change the locale on Mac, I don't know how many times I have to copy-paste this in here: `I'm using a Mac and tried changing the language in ... ... the system settings for language for Safari (to a language that displays numbers as 1 234), none of which made any difference.`

Comment: Did you try this - as suggested in the link I posted? 
`defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleLocale -string "fr_FR@currency=EUR"` and reboot - the `-string` was important